# How can I design a magical weapon that grants an advantage against fire-base creatures without using water and choking effects?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, house-rules, planes

The party I am DM'ing is going for an adventure to the Elemental Plane of Fire. I want to design a magical weapon that can grant an advantage against fire-based creatures. I see that Fire Elementals have Water Susceptibility (Cold Damage) but I have already house-ruled that elemental planes can not include magical effects of elements from other elemental planes, but just the spells that have elements of the current plane can be cast (as the plane purely consists of element of itself). For example, in the Elemental Plane of Air, not only Earth-based spells but all the spells are impeded, except air-based ones.

After I realized that I can't use a magical weapon that has cold damage due to my house-rule, I wanted to give the weapon a "heavy smoke" effect to choke the fire, as I thought that fire can not live without oxygen. But this option conflicts with my house-rule, also I saw that the fire-based creatures any other fire source in the Elemental Plane of Fire don't need air to live.

Now I have no idea how can I design a magical weapon that gives an advantage against fire-based creatures without cold damage and choking the fire via leaving without oxygen is not an option. I can not cancel my house-ruling because of the sake of my setting. I am open to any house ruling ideas beside the official ruling.

**TLDR: as in title, how can I design a magical weapon that grants an advantage against fire-base creatures without using water and choking effects?**

*If the question shows up to be opinion-based, please accept my apologies.*

Comment: What would the desired effect be, e.g. increased damage?

Comment: @ChumpNicholson Yes, increased damage is the main concern of the question.

Comment: Related Meta on [Close reasons for 'homebrew this for me' questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/close-reason-for-homebrew-this-for-me-questions).

Comment: @NautArch I understand, but I don't request any homebrew suggestion. Yes, my setting is homebrewed, but I intend to design my magical weapon within the boundaries of the rulebook. If so, this question would be never asked and I would design my weapon as I wish. Even I would set up a "homebrewed damage type".

Comment: @NautArch When I said "I am open to any house ruling ideas beside the official ruling.", I did not want people to house-rule for me. I meant I need rules but house-rule is welcome too. That might cause that confusion maybe... Sorry about that.

Comment: I understand that, but when you're asking "How can I do this", that's a request for suggestions. If instead you want to ask "Are there any existing items with mechanics that do this?", then that would be better.

Comment: @NautArch Okay, I see... I foresee this by the way, as I mentioned at the end of my question. But still, I thought that asking about rules of weapon designing wouldn't be opinion-based. But that's okay, thank you for your interest. =)

Comment: There are no rules about weapon designing, you can do whatever you want (for better or for worse!) :)

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer, to my mind, is simply to create a weapon that deals increased damage (or other desired effect) to a specific creature type, probably either flame elementals or creatures native to the elemental plane of fire. In this respect, it would be similar to a *sun blade*, which gets around the removal of undead radiant vulnerability by simply declaring that it deals extra damage to undead.